# Speed up slow WordPress query

Tags: mysql, wordpress, performance

I have written a custom related vacancies query for my site, using the plugin WP Job Manager. When using query monitor, I keep getting that the query is very slow (5+ seconds).

I've implemented query caching, except this requires the query to run at least 1 time.

Is it possible to speed up a query like this even more?

```
    $location = get_post_meta($id, '_job_location', true);
    $category = get_post_meta($id, 'job_category_wo', true);
    $args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'job_listing',
    'numberposts' => 5,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'     => '_job_location',
            'value'   => $location,
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key'     => '_job_location',
                'value'   => $location,
                'compare' => '='
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'job_category_wo',
                'value'   => $category[0],
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        )
    )
);
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you show, you search for posts matching this condition:

```
_job_location = $region OR _job_location = $region AND job_category_wo LIKE $category[0]
```

You can simplify this expression to:

```
_job_location = $region
```

Boolean algebra says `(A) OR (A AND B)` is redundant. It's the same as simply `(A)`.

This would factor out the `OR` operation, which is hard for SQL to optimize.

P.S.: I think there are other mistakes in your example. You set a variable `$location` but later you use `$region`. Which is it?

Also you are not sanitizing any values to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Factoring out the 'or' operation gives a massive improvement, thanks! If I still have not enough related vacancies, then I can use a simpler query to add them. Looks like 2 queries are better than 1 at this point.